# Custom trigger AWS AutoScale

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-auto-scaling

I have an EC2 server running on AWS (nonstop working). I want to trigger another server group in Auto-scale group if this EC2 server's CPU reaches 70. How can I do this?

My Idea: Cloudwatch > Lambda > Trigger AutScale

If is there any good solution, i would like to hear that.

Comment: Read about the Amazon CloudWatch CPUUtilization metric [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html).

Comment: Be careful... When scaling-in, Auto Scaling will typically terminate the 'oldest' running instance. This means that your original instance would be terminated. If you always want to keep the original instance running and just add/remove extra instances, then set your [Control which Auto Scaling instances terminate during scale in - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html) accordingly.

Comment: Do you also want to scale-in when things are less busy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An auto-scaling group can trigger off any CloudWatch Alarm. So just setup your CloudWatch alarm, and configure your auto-scaling group to use it. No need to use Lambda for this.